# Find the cardinality of the quotient of $\mathbb R$ in respect to R

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, equivalence-relations, quotient-set

R is an equivalence relation defined as $xRy \Leftrightarrow a - b$ is an integer.

What is the cardinality of the quotient of $\mathbb R$ in respect to R? How would you prove it?

I thought about a bijection between $[0,1)$ to the quotient of $\mathbb R$ in respect to R, but can't figure out to prove it formally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is good. The set $[0,1)$ contains a single representative of each equivalence class.

Note that your equivalence classes are sets of the form $a+\mathbb Z, a\in[0,1)$. To see why, first note that if $a\in[0,1)$, then $a+1,a-1,a+2,...$ are all in $[a]$, since they differ from $a$ by an integer. Moreover, if $x-a=n\in \mathbb Z$, then $x=a+n$, and so  $x\in a+\mathbb Z$.

Also note that if $x,y\in[0,1)$ and $x\neq y$, then they are not in the same equivalence class, since their difference is not an integer.

So the collection {$a+\mathbb Z| a\in [0,1)$} is a subset of the quotient set, and the quotient set is a subset of the collection {$a+\mathbb Z|a\in [0,1)$}, which means that they are equal.

Comment: So, how would define the bijection? I'm pretty stuck on that.. maybe I misunderstand your solution

Comment: Since you have shown that the quotient set is EXACTLY the set {$a+\mathbb Z$}, you can easily find a bijection to $[0,1)$ via the natural map - $a+\mathbb Z \mapsto a$. It's pretty simple to show that this is a bijection using the arguements above, and so the cardinality is aleph (just like $[0,1)$)

Comment: yeah, just got it! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For any $\;r\in \Bbb R\;$ there exists a unique $\;x_r\in[0,1)\;$ s.t. $\;r-x_r\in\Bbb Z\;$. We can see this as follows:

$$\text{Let us write}\;\;r=\lfloor r\rfloor+\{r\}$$

with $\;\lfloor r\rfloor =\,$ the floor function and $\;\{r\}=\;$  the fractional part function. Here, we assume that $\;\{r\}\;$ is always non-negative, and thus for example $\;\{-1.4\}=0.6=r-\lfloor r\rfloor\;$, and in any case

$$\{x\}=\left|\,\lfloor x\rfloor - x\,\right|$$

Thus, for any $\;r\in\Bbb R\;$ , we have that $\;x_r=\{r\}\;\implies r\in [\{r\}]\;$ , meaning: $\;x-\{r\}\in\Bbb Z\;$. Clearly, the element in $\;\{r\}\;$ in $\;[0,1)\;$ is unique, and thus thus $\;\left|\Bbb R/R\right|=|[0,1)|=2^{\aleph_0}\;$

Answer (score 0):

You should understand that this is just an instance of congruence modulo 1.

You have the equivalence class, you should be able to establish a bijection between these and the reals easily enough, yes?